Build Android with Vuforia. Error VuforiaLicense.cs
I use Unity 2022.3.28 LTS e Vuforia 10.22.5. When i create a Build in Android, this is the info message. I know it isn't an Error message, but i would like to know why it searches a License file that doesn't exist.
Invalid AssetDatabase path: C:/Users/napol/Desktop/TESTVUFORIA/TESTVUFORIA/Assets\VuforiaLicense.cs. Use path relative to the project folder.
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
Vuforia.EditorClasses.LicenseKeyObfuscationTask:Execute ()
BuildObserver/<>c:b__3_0 (Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask)
System.Collections.Generic.List1<Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask>:ForEach (System.Action1<Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask>)
BuildObserver:OnPreprocessBuild (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
Can anyone help me?

It's likely getting fixed in an upcoming release of Vuforia Engine. See the GitHub issue on the same topic: https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/120#issuecomment-2122742534
